# Unble to deploy function from Visual Studio Code to Azure Function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am not able to deploy function from VS Code to an Azure Function app. I'm getting the following error:

```
``
10:07:51 AM nilee1989: Starting deployment...
10:07:51 AM nilee1989: Creating zip package...
10:07:51 AM nilee1989: Zip package size: 2.46 kB
10:07:59 AM nilee1989: Updating submodules.
10:08:00 AM nilee1989: Preparing deployment for commit id '03ee2bab-1'.
10:08:00 AM nilee1989: PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
10:08:00 AM nilee1989: PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
10:08:00 AM nilee1989: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
10:08:00 AM nilee1989: Running oryx build...
10:08:00 AM nilee1989: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9.7 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Oryx Version: 0.2.20210120.1, Commit: 66c7820d7df527aaffabd2563a49ad57930999c9, ReleaseTagName: 20210120.1
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Build Operation ID: |PDmxDnGBBJ8=.b82ab75a_
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Repository Commit : 03ee2bab-16c8-41f0-ab2c-4b613e4a196b
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Detecting platforms...
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Detected following platforms:
10:08:02 AM nilee1989:   python: 3.9.7
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Version '3.9.7' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
10:08:02 AM nilee1989: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.9.7' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7'...
10:08:04 AM nilee1989: Downloaded in 2 sec(s).
10:08:04 AM nilee1989: Verifying checksum...
10:08:04 AM nilee1989: Extracting contents...
10:08:08 AM nilee1989: Done in 6 sec(s).
10:08:08 AM nilee1989: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
10:08:08 AM nilee1989: Running pip install...
10:08:08 AM nilee1989: [04:38:08+0000] Collecting azure-functions
10:08:08 AM nilee1989: [04:38:08+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (165 kB)
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: [04:38:09+0000] Installing collected packages: azure-functions
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: [04:38:09+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.15.0
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 23.1.2 is available.
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.7/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Done in 1 sec(s).
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Preparing output...
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Done in 0 sec(s).
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Removing existing manifest file
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Creating a manifest file...
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Manifest file created.
10:08:09 AM nilee1989: Done in 7 sec(s).
10:08:10 AM nilee1989: Running post deployment command(s)...
10:08:10 AM nilee1989: Generating summary of Oryx build
10:08:10 AM nilee1989: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
10:08:10 AM nilee1989: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Linux Consumption plan has a 1.5 GB memory limit on a remote build container.
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: To check our service limit, please visit https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Writing the artifacts to a squashfs file
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Parallel mksquashfs: Using 1 processor
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Creating 4.0 filesystem on /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs, block size 131072.
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: [===============================================================|] 141/141 100%
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, gzip compressed, data block size 131072
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  duplicates are removed
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Filesystem size 323.26 Kbytes (0.32 Mbytes)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  26.60% of uncompressed filesystem size (1215.22 Kbytes)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Inode table size 1492 bytes (1.46 Kbytes)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  28.77% of uncompressed inode table size (5186 bytes)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Directory table size 1551 bytes (1.51 Kbytes)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  37.21% of uncompressed directory table size (4168 bytes)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of duplicate files found 3
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of inodes 162
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of files 144
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of fragments 11
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of symbolic links  0
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of device nodes 0
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of fifo nodes 0
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of socket nodes 0
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of directories 18
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of uids 1
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  root (0)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Number of gids 1
10:08:11 AM nilee1989:  root (0)
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Malformed SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE when uploading built content.
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Generating summary of Oryx build
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
10:08:11 AM nilee1989: Deployment Failed. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
10:08:30 AM nilee1989: Deployment failed.
```

This is the `init.py` file which I am going to deploy from local computer to Azure Function app (cloud):

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

I had deleted function app from azure function cloud portal and created again, even when I tried to deploy this same above code from other system, but still getting the same error.

Please sugme how I can solve this problem.

Comment: I can able to deploy the above code to my function app. Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/k08MOzE.png).

Comment: In your output error shows that you need to install Python version 3.9.7. Use this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-397/) to install the Python version and try to deploy it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this exact problem today.
What helped me was adding `AzureWebJobsStorage` into Configuration of my Function App.

[image]

Enter as value the storage key's connection string from your Storage account. The path:

```
Storage account -> Access keys -> key 1 -> Connection string
```

I'm very new to Azure but I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I tried different ways, to create a function app inside the visual studio code. and deleted a previous function app. and automatically that newly function app synced with my azure account. and after I did deeply function to azure and it worked fine. but I will try your step as well for the newly created function app.